# How to check if a point is inside Skobbler map?

Tags: objective-c, skobbler-maps

With MapKit there's 
`MKMapRectContainsPoint(self.mkMapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate));` and I need to do something similar with a Skobbler map instance.

Comment: Please add further information. What have you tried so far, how does your instance look like etc.? Do you have code to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works pretty well:

```
CGPoint point = [self.skobblerMapView pointForCoordinate:yourCoordinate];
BOOL containsCoordinate = CGRectContainsPoint(self.skobblerMapView.bounds, point);
```